# Change permissions of folders between network company

Tags: linux, windows-10

Good morning,
I have a shared folder between linux and windows, however I can only enter the shared folder outside of my network company. Can someone help me enter this folder, with my network company?
I have windows 10, the shared folder was configured with the cifs protocol in linux. I'm the administrator.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are going to have to provide us specifics.  In addition to specifics on how the shared folder was configured, are you an Administrator, being a local Administrator might not be enough if you are connected to an AD domain. Edit your question, do not submit a comment, information required to answer your question should be in the question body instead of a comment.

Comment: I edited the question